# automatically add form input field based on input value

Tags: javascript, html

can someone help me please ?
i have a hidden input field with value. for example **3**.
based on that value (3) i want to automatically generate 3 input fields like this.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" name="guest" value="3" hidden>
        <div id="container">
        
            <!-- input field 1 -->
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <select name="title" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="first name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control"><br>
            <label for="last name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <!-- input field 2 -->
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <select name="title" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="first name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control"><br>
            <label for="last name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <br>
            
            <!-- input field 3 -->
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <select name="title" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="first name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control"><br>
            <label for="last name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i have try the dynamic input with button, but in my case i don't want to use a button to add a new input fields.

Comment: What will the three input field contain? you want just an input field with label or complete form?

Comment: its already inside the  form tag, i just want a input field and a label, so i can save it to my database

Comment: @Mamad when you say ""I just want a input field and a label", do you mean this set of `label`, `select`, `option`, and `input` elements that you show in your example? Or do you mean just a new `input` and `label` element?

Comment: yes, i want that set of `label`, `select`, `option` and `input` elements that i show in my example